# php split string with repeated delimiter

Tags: php, json, regex

How do I split the following string which is seperated by the ',' delimiter to an array in PHP?

String:

```
[{"sku":"PAP","name":"Butter","price":23,"quantity":2},{"sku":"PER","name":"Garlic","price":25,"quantity":1}]
```

Required Array:

```
$array[0]= "sku":"PAP","name":"Butter","price":23,"quantity":2

$array[1]= "sku":"PER","name":"Garlic","price":25,"quantity":1
```

I am not able to split based on the delimiter',' since it is present in the array elements.

Comment: The string looks very much like JSON. So you should use `json_decode` function: `$array = json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: You should be using a JSON parser here, not a regex.  Even more true if the JSON is nested.

Answer (score 1):

@Ruslan Osmanov is right.
Just decode like JSON.

```
<?php
  $a='[{"sku":"PAP","name":"Butter","price":23,"quantity":2},{"sku":"PER","name":"Garlic","price":25,"quantity":1}]';
  print_r(json_decode($a));
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sku] => PAP
            [name] => Butter
            [price] => 23
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [sku] => PER
            [name] => Garlic
            [price] => 25
            [quantity] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you that helps .Could you also suggest me how to assign each element to an array.. I am not able to access the individual elements of the decoded json string

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the unwanted characters:

```
$str=str_replace("[{","",$str);
$str=str_replace("}]","",$str);
```

Then, split with:

```
$array=preg_split("},{",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

string looks like in JSON so please use json_decode() method of php.